# CurrencyPipe and currencyCode in Ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, currency-pipe

I'm developing a application where I want currency will be show with currency code depending locale configuration at the device.
I'm trying with globalization native ionic plugin. All works fine if I write in my code the currency Code (e.g. EUR) but I'd like get it from locale config.

I can't find any way to do this. All examples I've found are writing currency Code. Then I'm asking if I'm trying to do something imposible.

Thanks...

Comment: Can you tell what is this `locate config`?

Comment: @AhsanAyaz Sorry, I mean locale

Comment: Can you show an example of code that you use, to provide some context. For instance are you trying to use the `getCurrencyPattern()` method in Ionic native plugin?

Comment: @Sébastien This is part of my problem, getCurrencyPattern need currencyCode as parameter (EUR, USD, etc...). Just my problem is I couldn't find the way to get it from locale device configuration.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging I don't think there is a straighforward way of getting the currency from device information or locale.

The reason may be that there is not obvious link between language, location and currency used for making purchases.

The only external hint that you could use, might be through using the "In App Purchase 2" Ionic native plugin.

This does require activating In App Billing for your app in the Google Play store, or In App Purchase in the Apple App Store. Then, once you've created (non-free) products, you could check which currency is used in the product listings you receive from the store and take it as a hint regarding the user's preferred currency.

Other than that my best guess is to assume a default currency and manually assign a specific currency per locale.

### What I have tested

- all info available from the [Ionic Device](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device/) native plugin
- all info available from the [Ionic Globalization](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/globalization/) native plugin

None of these gave me any direct info regarding the user's preferred currency.

I'd like to get a better answer...

Comment: Ok, Probably I'll search other way like set an array with all currencies and let user choose this in app configure view . Thanks for all

Comment: Please post if you find a real solution.